# Geometry Nodes: Set Curve Line end at Global Z=0 (Blender 3.5.1)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, instances, coordinates

I'm trying to use geometry nodes to create a support system for 3D printing with a thin wall as the connection point:

[image]

What I want to do is have columns going from the B points down to the floor at Global Z=0.

What I'm trying to do is make the columns with instanced Curve Lines, that I can give a round profile later for thickness. The B points are not actually there. The original Points on the curve are 'A' and I instanced the Cones there and moved them in their Z direction down by the height of the the curve profile 'h' and the height of the cones 'H'.

I used the offset of the Cones as the starting point of the Curve Line but I have no idea how to set the coordinates of the End point to be at Global Z=0 (C points). Is there a way to do so?
(I don't know if this would be the best method to begin with, I'm fine with doing it differently too).

I would also want to later Instance the base of the supports on the C points (A Cone Primitive would work, rather than that object specifically)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like so?

[image]

try this:

[image]

Comment: Yea, that works pretty well, thanks. The only issue I see is that Z position has to be set manually and changes with the position of the Origin of the curve. Is there a way to somehow get the Z component of the curve's origin to use that in the Add Vector math node? If not, then I guess I can just apply the Location of the curve and remove the Add Vector Math al together since the previous node is already setting it to 0

Comment: yes, of course, you could use raycast on a plane which is on z = 0.